# How should I include a class attribute in only one anchor tag out of several anchor tags in a table in MVC User Control?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a user control in mvc 2.0, where i have a table of anchor tags created by using `Html.ActionLink(title,action,controller)`. Now out of these several anchor tags, one will have a particular class applied to it, what is the best method to do this ?

> Darin:) Using this, I will have to apply the conditional logic in the view itself, i have to apply class to only one of the several anchor tags based on the action. In this case I will have to check 20 times if this is the action, if I have 20 anchor tags. I want something like inherited class out of ActionLink which will check the action and apply the class based on it to only one of the anchor tags.

Comment: please see my updated answer about writing a custom HTML helper which would allow you to apply the CSS class conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) which allows you to pass html attributes such as a CSS class:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(title, action, controller, null, new { @class = "foo" }) %>
```

---

UPDATE:

You could also write a custom ActionLink helper which would do the job:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText,
        string actionName,
        string controllerName
    )
    {
        if (SomeLogic())
        {
            // If some logic is verified you could apply the CSS class
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
                linkText, 
                actionName, 
                controllerName, 
                null,
                new { @class = "foo" }
            );
        }
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
            linkText, 
            actionName, 
            controllerName, 
        );
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
<%= Html.MyActionLink(title, action, controller) %>
```

Comment: In which folder in MVC project, should I save this file ? And how will I access the current action in this helper extension method ?

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja, for example you could save it in a `HtmlExtensions.cs` file inside a subfolder called `Extensions`. Then you need to bring the namespace in which this class was declared into scope inside your view `<%@ Import Namespace="Namespace.Containing.The.HtmlExtensions.Class" %>` and then you could use it as shown in my post. You could also add this namespace into the `namespaces` section in your web.config in which case your HTML helper would be globally accessible in all views. Also checkout the documentation: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs